# PHPExcel Protect a single column

Tags: cell, phpexcel

I have issues with cell protection.

I would like to protect just one column, B for example.

So I tried:

```
$sheet->getProtection()->setSheet(true);   
$highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow();

$sheet->getStyle('A1:J2000)->getProtection()->setLocked( PHPExcel_Style_Protection::PROTECTION_UNPROTECTED );

for($i=1;$i<=$highestRow;$i++)
{
  $sheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow(1,$i)->getProtection()->setLocked(PHPExcel_Style_Protection::PROTECTION_PROTECTED);
}
```

But it's really slow, and not good because if I need to open my sheet again
`$highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow();` will return "J".

Another solution would be to get the last non-empty column, do you know how to do that? Because `getHighestRow(Column)` return the columns unprotected or empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop is slow because you're applying the style to each individual cell, rather than to the range of cells demonstrated in your

```
$sheet->getStyle('A1:J2000)->getProtection()->setLocked( PHPExcel_Style_Protection::PROTECTION_UNPROTECTED );
```

line
: one call to set the style for a range of 1000 cells is more that 1000 times faster than applying it to each of 1000 cells individually.

```
$sheet->getHighestDataRow();
```

will return the highest row in the worksheet that contains actual data values

```
$sheet->getHighestDataColumn();
```

is the column equivalent

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Are you sure for getHighestDataRow ? i had heard about it in an other subject on this website, but i don't see this funtion in the PHPExcel's doc and when i try to use it, i have an error PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined method PHPExcel_Worksheet::getHighestDataColumn()

Comment: What version of PHPExcel are you running? getHighestDataColumn() and getHighestDataRow() were added as new methods for the worksheet object in version 1.7.7

Answer (score 2):

First you can protect complete sheet. After that you can uprotect others. This code will protect the first column and first

```
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setSheet(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B2:Z400')->getProtection()->setLocked(PHPExcel_Style_Protection::PROTECTION_UNPROTECTED);
```